# No provider for configService when trying to bootstrap with APP_INITIALIZER injector

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to load config.json file from the external source/asset folder.
I have created **AppConfigService** which loads the config data  and returns the promise as expected by APP_INITIALIZER.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

loadAppConfig() {
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
       console.log(data)
      });
  }
```

}

Here is my providers array

```
 providers: [
 {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: appInitializerFn,
  multi: true,
  deps: [AppConfigService]
},
```

and factory

```
const appInitializerFn = (config: AppConfigService)  => {
  return () => {
return config.loadAppConfig();
};  };
```

i'm getting error

> NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> AppConfigService]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> AppConfigService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for AppConfigService!

Comment: Did you add the `AppConfigService` as a provider in your `AppModule` ?

Comment: Somehow i missed it, thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing in AppModule. But you can easily register your service on the service metadata itself like below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}

or 

 @Injectable({
      providedIn: CustomModuleName
    }
```